# Optimized solution for a rolling dice code puzzle

Tags: php, arrays, puzzle

I was asked to provide the solution of this rolling dice problem in an interview. When I showed him my solution, he said that there is another way to find the solution. I am looking for answer in PHP script only.

> Question:
>
> Two persons are playing a game of rolling 2 dices. Each person rolls the two dices n times and records the outcomes (sum of value of two dices) of all the n attempts. So after n attempts of both the player we have two list corresponding to the n outcomes of two players.
>
> They want to know that whether they have got all possible outcomes( 1 to 12) same number of times or not. If they got all the possible outcomes same number of times then they are called lucky otherwise unlucky.
>
> **Input**: Two Integer Arrays (L1, L2) corresponding to outcomes of two players.
>
> **Output**: Lucky or Unlucky depending on the case

My Answer:

```
<?php
function rollingdice($input1,$input2)
{
  foreach($input1 as $k=>$a)
  { 
    if(in_array($a,$input2))
    {$p = array_search($a, $input2);
     unset($input2[$p]);
    }
    else
    { return 'Unlucky';}
  }
return 'Lucky';
}
?>
```

Comment: what is "sol" and  "soln" ?

Comment: edited its solution ..

Comment: Perhaps something using array_count_values?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking to improve existing code. It may be a better fit for Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: chrisForrence at least here some guy see  ... though I have duplicated it there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function rollingdice($input1,$input2)
{
  $a = array_count_values($input1);
  $b = array_count_values($input2);

  if(array_diff_assoc($a,$b) || array_diff_assoc($b,$a)) { return 'Unlucky';}

  return 'Lucky';
}
```

Comment: in foreach we have to check the key I think as dice value after array_count_values becomes key for $a and $b..

Comment: I simplified solution